# Method Paste failed, but code looks simple (and have worked before)

Tags: vba

What is wrong with this code?:

```
Private Sub Copy_Images()
    Dim wks, wks2 As Worksheet        
    Set wks = Sheets("export")        
    Set wks2 = Sheets("HomePage")    
    wks2.Activate    
    wks2.Shapes("picture").Copy    
    wks.Activate    
    wks.Paste Range("A1")    
End Sub
```

---

Error: Method 'Paste' of object '_Worksheet' failed - 1004

Comment: which line gets marked? well, seems to be line wks.Paste, my mistake. I take a look at it.

Comment: First of all: If you state `Dim wks, wks2 As Worksheet`, only wks2 will be declared as a Worksheet. wks will be a Variant, but this should work nonetheless. Second: It works for me (after adapting sheet and shape names)

Comment: I don't understand why you would dim the worksheets anyway, unless your code is way longer than this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Copy_Images()

Dim wks as worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet

Set wks = Sheets("export")
Set wks2 = Sheets("HomePage")

    wks2.Shapes("picture").Copy
    wks.range("A1").Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: Basically, this does the same as the original code.

Comment: I didn't know the `sheets(1).paste range("A1")` would work as well. In that case I would suggest the TS to check the names of the worksheets he has set.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Private Sub Copy_Images()
  Dim wks As Worksheet 
  Dim wks2 As Worksheet        
  Set wks = Sheets("export")        
  Set wks2 = Sheets("HomePage")    
  wks2.Activate    
  wks2.Shapes("picture").Copy    
  wks.Activate 
  Range("A1").Select   
  ActiveSheet.Paste   
End Sub
```

Comment: This also does the same as the original code AND adds an unnecessary Select-statement, which should be avoided completely.